# Excel cells with hyperlinks

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-office

I have an excel file where the cells have a short text and an hyperlink associated to it.  I want o export the data to a csv file, but I need the url be written as well in the final file. How can I do it? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want a comma between the two items ??

Comment: ^If I understand this correctly, the current file *only* has one item (the short text), and he wants the end product to *only* have the URL

Comment: Yes, thats it @YangLi. Thanks

Comment: @Miguel Right, I'll see if I can write a short macro to do this

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought this would soluble with a simple click here and there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way you can do it using macros.

Imagine that this is your spreadsheet

[image: Spreadsheet]

Now, you want to create a macro by pressing `Alt + F8`

Name it something like "HyperlinkExpander", like this:

[image: createmacro]

Now you should be at the editor, if not then press `Alt + F11`. In the window, paste the following code:

```
Sub HyperlinkExpander()

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If c.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        c.Value = c.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Now go back to your spreadsheet and highlight all cells you want to convert. It does not matter if you highlight cells you don't want to convert, as it will not change cells without links.

Once you've highlighted them, go back to the editor (`Alt + F11`) and press `F5` to run. Now it should expand your hyperlinks:

[image: finishedexpand]